# Expectation of a function of the sample covariance matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, sample, eigenvalues

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ and let $\hat\Sigma$ be the sample covariance matrix calculated from an iid sample $X_1, \dots, X_N$. Also, let $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ be the orthonormal eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ associated with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ respectively, where $i \neq j$.

[*A Quadratic Discriminant Function Based on Bias Rectification
of Eigenvalues*](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/1520-684X%28200008%2931%3A9%3C28%3A%3AAID-SCJ4%3E3.0.CO%3B2-V) (Sakai et al. 2000) equation 12 states this result, without proof:

$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\phi_i^\top\hat\Sigma\phi_j\right)^2\right] = \frac{\lambda_i\lambda_j}{N-1}.
$$

How should the proof be approached? Any explanations of the approach or sources are appreciated.

Comment: @User1865345 thanks for adding the link to the paper and fixing the LaTeX! It's the little things that count...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a quite challenging and interesting problem as it calls for many classical results of multivariate Gaussian distribution and technical matrix operations. To begin with, note that since $\hat{\Sigma}$ is invariant under translation, we can assume $\mu = 0$ in the calculation.

Suppose $X$ is a $m$-variate Gaussian vector. Introduce the following notations:
\begin{align*}
Z = \begin{bmatrix}
X_1^T \\
\vdots \\
X_N^T
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times m}, \;
e = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}, \;
\bar{X} = N^{-1}\sum_{k = 1}^NX_k \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}.
\end{align*}
By definition,
\begin{align*}
(N - 1)\hat{\Sigma} = \sum_{k = 1}^N(X_k - \bar{X})(X_k - \bar{X})^T = Z^T(I_{(N)} - N^{-1}ee^T)Z := Z^TPZ \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\phi_i^T\hat{\Sigma}\phi_j = \frac{1}{N - 1}(Z\phi_i)^TP(Z\phi_j). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}

My strategy is trying to leverage the [expectation and variance of Gaussian quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)). To this end, we need to rewrite $\eqref{1}$ in terms of [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of $Z^T$ so that $\phi_i, \phi_j$ can be absorbed into the central non-random matrix.  In detail, denote $\operatorname{vec}(Z^T) \in \mathbb{R}^{N^2 \times 1}$ by $\xi$, then $\xi \sim N_{N^2}(0, I_{(N)} \otimes \Sigma)$. It can be verified that
\begin{align*}
G &:= (N - 1)\phi_i^T\hat{\Sigma}\phi_j \\
&= \phi_i^TZ^TP(\phi_j^TZ^T)^T \\
&= (\operatorname{vec}(\phi_i^TZ^T))^TP\operatorname{vec}(\phi_j^TZ^T) \\
&= ((I_{(N)} \otimes \phi_i^T)\operatorname{vec}(Z^T))^TP
 (I_{(N)} \otimes \phi_j^T)\operatorname{vec}(Z^T) \\
&= \xi^T (I_{(N)} \otimes \phi_i)P(I_{(N)} \otimes \phi_j^T)\xi \\
&= \xi^T (P \otimes \phi_i)(I_{(N)} \otimes \phi_j^T)\xi \\
&= \xi^T (P\otimes (\phi_i\phi_j^T))\xi. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
In the derivation above,  the third equality used the fact that $v = \operatorname{vec}(v)^T$ for a row vector $v$. The fourth equality used the identity $\operatorname{vec}(ABC) = (C^T \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B)$. The fifth equality used $(A \otimes B)^T = A^T \otimes B^T$ and the definition $\xi = \operatorname{vec}(Z^T)$. The sixth and seventh equality used the identity $(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) = (AC)\otimes(BD)$ of Kronecker product.

It then follows [by the expectation of Gaussian quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Expectation) that
\begin{align*}
E[G] &= \operatorname{tr}((P\otimes (\phi_i\phi_j^T))(I_{(N)}\otimes\Sigma)) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(P \otimes (\phi_i\phi_j^T\Sigma)) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(P \otimes (\phi_i\lambda_j\phi_j^T)) \\
&= \operatorname{tr}(P)\operatorname{tr}(\lambda_j\phi_i\phi_j^T) \\
&= (N - 1)\lambda_j\phi_j^T\phi_i = 0. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align*}
In the derivation above, the second equality used the condition $\Sigma\phi_j = \lambda_j\phi_j$. The fourth equality used the property $\operatorname{tr}(A \otimes B) = \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$ of Kronecker product and trace. The fifth equality used the property $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$ of trace and the fact $\operatorname{tr}(P) = N - 1$.  In the last equality, we used the orthogonality between $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$. The same properties will be used repeatedly in the variance calculation below, where I will skip explaining them during the application.

To compute the variance of $G$, note that since the matrix $\Lambda := P\otimes (\phi_i\phi_j^T)$ is non-symmetric because $i \neq j$ and the variance formula only applies to the symmetric matrix, we need to symmetrize $\Lambda$ first (see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Computing_the_variance_in_the_non-symmetric_case)) then apply the [variance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)#Variance_in_the_Gaussian_case) as follows:
\begin{align*}
& \operatorname{Var}(G) = \operatorname{Var}\left(\xi^T\frac{\Lambda + \Lambda^T}{2}\xi\right) \\
=& 2\operatorname{tr}\left(\frac{1}{4}(\Lambda + \Lambda^T)(I_{(N)} \otimes \Sigma) (\Lambda + \Lambda^T)(I_{(N)} \otimes \Sigma)\right)\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}\left((\Lambda + \Lambda^T)(I_{(N)} \otimes \Sigma) (\Lambda + \Lambda^T)(I_{(N)} \otimes \Sigma)\right)\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(P \otimes (\phi_i\phi_j^T\Sigma) + P \otimes (\phi_j\phi_i^T\Sigma)\right)^2\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(\lambda_j P \otimes (\phi_i\phi_j^T) + \lambda_i P \otimes (\phi_j\phi_i^T)\right)^2\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\lambda_i\lambda_j\operatorname{tr}\left(P \otimes (\phi_i\phi_i^T) + P \otimes (\phi_j\phi_j^T) \right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\lambda_i\lambda_j\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(P \otimes (\phi_i\phi_i^T)\right) + \operatorname{tr}\left(P \otimes (\phi_j\phi_j^T) \right)\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\lambda_i\lambda_j\left(\operatorname{tr}(P)\operatorname{tr}(\phi_i\phi_i^T) + \operatorname{tr}(P)\operatorname{tr}(\phi_j\phi_j^T)\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\lambda_i\lambda_j\left(\operatorname{tr}(P)\operatorname{tr}(\phi_i^T\phi_i) + \operatorname{tr}(P)\operatorname{tr}(\phi_j^T\phi_j)\right) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\lambda_i\lambda_j\left((N - 1) \times 1 + (N - 1) \times 1\right) \\
=& \lambda_i\lambda_j(N - 1). \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}

In the above derivation, the fifth equality used the condition $\Sigma\phi_i = \lambda_i\phi_i, \Sigma\phi_j = \lambda_j\phi_j$. The sixth equality used the fact $\phi_i^T\phi_j = \phi_j^T\phi_i = 0$.  The tenth equality used the facts $\operatorname{tr}(P) = N - 1$ and $\phi_i^T\phi_i = \phi_j^T\phi_j = 1$.

Combining $\eqref{2}, \eqref{3}, \eqref{4}$ then yields
\begin{align*}
E[(\phi_i\hat{\Sigma}\phi_j)^2] = \frac{1}{(N - 1)^2}E[G^2] = 
\frac{1}{(N - 1)^2}(\operatorname{Var}(G) + (E[G])^2) = \frac{\lambda_i\lambda_j}{N - 1}, 
\end{align*}
as desired.